# Does the function Solve determine if a polynomial is NOT solvable by radicals?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

If I input:

```
Solve[x^5 - x - 1 == 0, x]
(* {{x -> Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 1]}, {x -> 
   Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 2]}, {x -> Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 3]}, {x ->
    Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 4]}, {x -> Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 5]}} *)
```

$x^5 - x - 1=0$ is NOT solvable by radicals (according to various sources).

My question is:

When *Mathematica* does not return an exact solution to a polynomial equation (as in the above example), does this imply that the polynomial is not solvable by radicals?

Comment: But `Solve` did return an exact solution set. `Root` objects **are** exact solutions.

Comment: Have a look at `Quartics` in the documentations.

Comment: Maybe a better way to state my question is this:  Does there exists an algorithm that can determine if a polynomial equation is "solvable by radicals"?

Comment: The direct answer to your question is *no*, and this is documented in `tutorial/AlgebraicNumbers`. It is indicated there that `Solve[x^6 - 9 x^4 - 4 x^3 + 27 x^2 - 36 x - 23 == 0, x]` returns a list of `Root` objects but that `2^(1/3) + 3^(1/2)` is a solution.

Comment: @murray.  Yes, thank you.  This is the answer that I expected, along with the documentation to substantiate it.

Comment: It is not solvable in radicals, but that is not the same as algebraic solution that includes hypergeometric functions and Bring radicals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This is to put murray's comment on record, so it can be accepted by the OP.*

The direct answer to your question is no, and this is documented in [tutorial/AlgebraicNumbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AlgebraicNumbers.html). It is indicated there that

```
Solve[x^6 - 9 x^4 - 4 x^3 + 27 x^2 - 36 x - 23 == 0, x]
```

returns a list of root objects, even though `2^(1/3) + 3^(1/2)` is a solution